# Having difficulty uninstalling git from Windows computer

Tags: windows, git, uninstall, github

Whenever I attempt to uninstall git from the control panel, I get this error message:

[image: Git Error Message]

Problem is, I don't know where I can download this file: `unins000.exe`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The simplest way would be to reinstall Git.  You won't specifically find this file anywhere, and it isn't something we can provide you.

Comment: May be the git components have some corruptions, please try to repair it through Control Panel, and try to uninstall git again. Or we could download git, after that when you try to install it, tick repair option. After repaired, try to uninstall it again to check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution - but have you considered going into the file directory and deleting it manually? If yes, you can can do it one of two ways.

First way: Open file explorer, navigate to the folder and delete it.

Second way: Open command line, cd into parent directory and type rmdir -rf Git

Answer (score 0):

An easy and safe way to resolve this issue is to reinstall Git. This should resolve the missing uninstall information. Once reinstalled, you should be able to properly uninstall Git.